# Получить значение <input type=radio> элемента

Tags: javascript, html

Как в `javascript` установить элемент `input type=radio` как отмеченный, либо убрать отметку и получить - является ли элемент зачеканным в данный момент?

Я использую методы, наподобие

`roundThingy.setAttribute('checked', 'checked');`

и

`roundThingy.getAttribute('checked')`

но оно не работает.

Есть тестовый фрагмент:

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('input');
console.log('a =', a) //возвращает 5 узлов

function listen() {
  for (elem in a) {
    console.log('a.checked =', a.checked); // возвращает undefined 11 раз
    if (elem.checked) {
      console.log(true)
    } else {
      console.log(false)
    } // возвращает false 11 раз
  }
}
```

```html
 <input type="radio" name="azaza" onchange="listen();" />один
  <input type="radio" name="azaza" onchange="listen();" />два
  <input type="radio" name="azaza" onchange="listen();" />три
  <input type="radio" name="azaza" onchange="listen();" />четыре
  <input type="radio" name="azaza" onchange="listen();" />пять
```

Comment: У `input` нет закрывающего тега

Comment: @Air Исправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

У `input` - атрибут `checked` служит для того,  если надо по умолчанию чтобы он был отмечен, как выразился автор **`чекнутым`**. И значения `false && true` не имеют особого значения.

А чтобы он не был `чекнутым`, надо удалить атрибут

`input.removeAttribute('checked')`

А чтобы проверить какой элемент `чекнутым` надо проверять свойство `input.checked`

```js
[...document.querySelectorAll('input')].forEach((s, i, arr) => {
  console.log(arr[i].checked);
  s.addEventListener('input', () => {
    console.log('==========================');
    console.log(s, ' : ', i, ' : ', arr[i].checked);
  })
})
```

```html
<input value="я первый" name="r" type="radio" checked="false" />
<input value="я второй" name="r" type="radio" />
<input value="я третий" name="r" type="radio" />
```

Непосредственный ответ на вопрос автора

Цикл `for ( * in *)` возвращает объект в котором не только ключи прокручиваемых  элементов, но и его свойства.

> Надеюсь я правильно выразился.

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (let elem in a) {
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />один
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />два
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />три
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />четыре
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />пять
```

Чтобы получить непосредственно элемент не надо забывать про индекс
В данном примере `elem` - это индекс, а не сам элемент

```js
let a = document.querySelectorAll('input');
for (let elem in a) {
  if (a[elem].checked)
    console.log(elem);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="azaza" checked />один
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />два
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />три
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />четыре
<input type="radio" name="azaza" />пять
```

Comment: А если .checked только для установки значения по умолчанию, то какой атрибут отражает текущее состояние?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov, я не правильно понял вопрос.  Проверять состояние надо не присутствием или отсутствием атрибута. А свойством `input.checked`

Answer (score 1):

> Как в javascript установить элемент `<input type="radio" />` как отмеченный

Вы можете изначально в HTML установить атрибут `checked` для Вашей кнопки, если это требуется, для установки атрибута `checked` с помощью javascript посмотрите код ниже

```
<input id="rd_btn" type="radio" checked>
```

> является ли элемент зачеканным в данный момент?

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($("#rd_btn").prop('checked')) {
    // true
  } else {
    // false
  }
});
```

**Javascript**

```
var btn = document.getElementById('rd_btn');

if(btn.checked) {
  // true
} else {
  // false
}
```

Установить атрибут `checked` с помощью JS/jQuery

**jQuery 1.6+**

```
$('#rd_btn').prop('checked', true);
$('#rd_btn').prop('checked', false);
```

**jQuery 1.5 и ниже**

```
$('#rd_btn').attr('checked', true);
$('#rd_btn').attr('checked', false);
```

**Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("rd_btn").checked = true;
document.getElementById("rd_btn").checked = false;
```

Comment: Я добавил пример, Можете пожалуйста проверить почему код из примера не работает как запланировано?

Comment: @IgorCheglakov, как я полагаю, вы хотите на изменение `input`'a делать какое-то действие? Поправте меня, если я не прав.